# CSS word targeting

Tags: html, css

I need to style a specific word with CSS, but I'm not sure how I would be able to do this.
For some reason I can't assign any ID's or Classes to the elements of a list, this is the example:

`<ul class="xxx">
<li><a href="#" class="xxx"><span class="yyy">White</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="xxx"><span class="yyy">Black</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="xxx"><span class="yyy">Blue</span></a></li>
</ul>`

For example, the word `white` with `color: white;`
I cannot use nth-child because in a page on my website the order of the li can be different.

I was wondering if there is a way with CSS, to tell the color only of the li (or span) which contains white.

Is there anyone who knows how I could do this?
Thank you!

Comment: No, CSS cannot detect content...it styles whole elements not parts of one.

Answer (score 1):

You should assign a class on them:

```
<ul class="xxx"> 
   <li><a href="#" class="xxx"><span class="yyy white">White</span></a></li> 
   <li><a href="#" class="xxx"><span class="yyy black">Black</span></a></li> 
   <li><a href="#" class="xxx"><span class="yyy blue">Blue</span></a></li> 
</ul>
```

And then apply the color:

```
.white{
    color: white;
}
.black{
    color: black;
}
.blue{
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure "I cant assign any IDs to the elements of a list" means that OP can't modify the HTML at all.

Comment: The OP is saying can't assign the IDs not class...

Comment: The OP is saying this because there may be lots of white color divs/spans so can't assign the ID because id is unique. This is what OP is reffering...

Comment: I'm really not sure how you can possibly know that based on what the OP has stated in the question...

Comment: just a common sense! (I may be wrong too!)

Comment: Ok, James Donnelly is right! I cant assign ID or CLASS

Comment: But from the comment of Paulie i think i cannot do this because "CSS cannot detect content", its right?

Comment: Yes, there's no other way around...